# Should I use str_replace instead of substr?

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm using a data feed plugin that has a custom PHP function that allows me to rewrite every Buy_URL in the feed. Say, for example, one of the original Buy_URLs is this:

```
http://www.affiliatecompa.com/product/clean.com?ref=ab
```

I want to rewrite the beginning and the end of the URL with

"http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com"

and

"laik"` respectively. so that it should become:

```
http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com/product/clean.com?ref=laik
```

I contacted the author of the plugin and he told me to put the following code in the function.php in my theme and then call the function in the plugin

```
function WOKI_Change_Url($x){
    $y = substr($x, 29);
    $y = substr($y, -2);
    return "http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com" . $y . 'laik';
}
```

Apparently it doesn't work because it removes any other part of the URL and every Buyurl has now become

```
http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.comlaik
```

I suspect that substr isn't right for what I want to do in this case. Should I use str_replace instead in the function?

Comment: check out the functions: [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` can fit for what you are trying to do, but his method can work as well. He just left out a parameter on `substr()`. His code should work with that parameter added back in (assuming that you always have a 2-character value in the `ref=ab` part of the string:

```
function WOKI_Change_Url($x){
    $y = substr($x, 29);
    $y = substr($y, 0, -2); //the 0 here tells it to use the whole string, minus the last two chars; without the zero, this would muck things up a lot
    return "http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com" . $y . 'laik';
}
```

As to `str_replace()`, that too could work if you know the value of what you are trying to replace, but things get complicated with escaping using str_replace. If it is always exactly `ref=ab` to be replaced with `ref=laik` then the following should work (using `urlencode()` to perform the escaping):

```
function WOKI_Change_Url($x){
    $y = str_replace($x, "ref=ab", "ref=laik"); //this replaces the ref=ab part
    return "http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com" . urlencode($y);
}
```

Note that if you do not know for sure that it will always be `ab` that you are replacing, you may need to employ [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead, with a regular expression to replace anything that comes after `ref=`. Something like:

```
function WOKI_Change_Url($x){
    $y = preg_replace("/ref=.*/", "ref=laik", $x); //this replaces the ref= part for anything... but I haven't tested it
    return "http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com" . urlencode($y);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tried them all, but unfortunately, none of them work. substr() just puts "http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com" and "laik" together instead of rewriting the beginning and the end of the URL.   preg_replace and str_replace() just replace the entire URL with "http://www.dsqce.com/click-111111-1111XX111?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affiliatecompa.com". I'll keep working on it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that something is preventing the source url from being passed in to the function as a parameter. Can you update the question with an example of the relevant code where the `WOKI_Change_Url` function is called? The behavior you describe fits what would happen if `$x` had no value.

Comment: You could verify this by adding `echo $x;` as the first line of each function, or if that doesn't work, by using `return $x;` in some tests to see what value the function gets for the source url.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. Do you mean adding echo $x; before "function WOKI_Change_Url($x){" ?

Comment: No - I meant adding it immediately after that line. There's a chance that you won't see the output of the echo statement though, so if adding it immediately after that line doesn't seem to do anything, then use `return $x;` instead.